# Blender crashes after rendering one frame

Tags: rendering

I'm very new to blender and I'm trying to render a short animation I created form a template. I've set up my rendering options/output properties following a guide I found, but after rendering a single frame (both as an animation and image), instead of saving the PNG to the correct destination, Blender just closes. I was told there could be something wrong with my output settings, so here's what I have:

https://gyazo.com/e30251ec66866b222abd9fb1d20b0188

I've tried changing my output location and selcting Cuda under preferences, neither worked.

Link to blend file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7y7qgoxncsyd3d0/20th%20Century%20Fox%20Template.blend?dl=0

Comment: If you'd like I could use my Sheepit points to render it for you to check if it's a problem with the blend file or your computer.

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Eevee? Can you also list your hardware specs? You might also want to post the blend file to see if anyone else can reproduce your crash.

Comment: @NascentSpace That would be great, if you wouldn't mind. Here's a link to the .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7y7qgoxncsyd3d0/20th%20Century%20Fox%20Template.blend?dl=0

Comment: @Cultmethod I'm using Eevee, though I've tried Cycles as well. I just attached the blend file to the original post. My specs are:

-RTX 2080ti
-32GB RAM
-i9 9900x

Comment: I've started rendering the animation, did you want all 600 frames?
https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/jobs.php

Comment: @NascentSpace You don't need to render the whole thing no, I just wanted to know if it was something my hardware/setup. I guess it is then?

Comment: Hmmm that's quite strange, when I tried to render it with eevee it immediately crashed. When rendered with cycles it renders the image and then crashes after completion. So it's possibly something wrong with the scene itself.

Comment: @NascentSpace Hmm ok. Anything in particular I should look out for?

Comment: Not entirely sure what the problem could be, try and hide some of the things in the scene and see if anything changes perhaps? Does this happen with other similar scenes? If you partially recreated it and tried rendering in a new project does the problem persist?

Comment: When you want to render you first bake your animation, then render it in silent mode with command line : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9IW96FisnU